# How to download yahoo finance csv in Scala?

Tags: scala

What's wrong with the second block of Scala code?

```
// Works:
println(scala.io.Source.fromURL("http://www.imdb.com").mkString)  

// Blank:
println(scala.io.Source.fromURL("http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=FB").mkString);
```

Comment: Most likely your url is wrong, probably because the service runs on https and not http

Comment: you are right, changed it to https and it worked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you url is `http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=FB` but the correct url for the service is `https://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=FB`.

The service runs on https. Trying to access with http will get you a redirect response which is what you are printing out.